# R - Counting occurrences of values in a column in data.frame

Tags: r

> I have a data.frame = patient

```
ID  GLUC TGL HDL LDL HRT  MAMM SMOKE
A   88   NA  32  99   Y   <NA>  ever
B   NA   150 60  NA  <NA>  no   never
C   110  NA  NA  120  N   <NA>  <NA>
D   NA   200 65  165 <NA>  yes  never
E   90   210 NA  150  Y   <NA>  never
F   88   NA  32  210 <NA>  yes  ever
G   120  164 NA  NA   Y    yes  <NA>
H   110  170 70  188 <NA> <NA>  ever
I   NA   190 NA  190  N    no   <NA>
J   90   NA  75  NA  <NA>  yes  never
```

---

I have to write a function and pass a vector containing one of more column 
    names as :`function(df=patient, var=c("HRT","MAMM"))`
    Then, get the count of occurrence of each character and NA in the respective 
    `columns(in this case "HRT","MAMM")` and display as follows: `Count(NA)= NMiss`.

**** OUTPUT I NEED****

```
varName group count
    1  HRT      N     2
    2           Y     3 
    3          NMiss  5
    4  MAMM     no    2
    5           yes   4
    6          NMiss  4
```

I am able to calculate the occurrences of N, Y, NA by using the following for one column.

```
NMiss= sum(is.na(patient$HRT))

 Y = length(which(patient$HRT=="Y"))

 N = length(which(patient$HRT=="N"))
```

However, I am not able to create the OUTPUT I NEED.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Look at `table` i.e. `lapply(dat[c("HRT","MAMM")], table, useNA="always")`

Comment: thank you thelatemail!  However, I need a function to pass variables as per choice. i.e. if I don't pass anything, then I should see NULL.  If I pass only one value, I should get to see the counts of Y, N,<>NA, yes, no for each of the passed column name.

Comment: And? Make it a function then. `f <- function(data, var) lapply(data[var], table, useNA="always")` and call it like `f(dat, c("HRT","MAMM"))`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the data frame already created with the updated values you can use the function `summary()` to obtain the result of the column that you want.

Comment: Summary won't quite be enough to return the desired output for the op as it seems like they want the counts of each occurrence grouped by the variables of another column.